# Why implementing an interface method private is accepted?

Tags: c#, interface

I'm studying interface and got into something weird interface stuff where the rule is we must implement an interface method public. But not in this example.

I've tried what I learned in my experience and the answer I've found really breaks the rule.

```
    public interface DropV1
    {
        void Ship();
    }

    public interface DropV2
    {
        void Ship();
    }
    //accepted by the editor
    class DropShipping : DropV1, DropV2
    {
        void DropV1.Ship() { }
        void DropV2.Ship() { }

    }
```

I was expecting in 1billion percent of the implementation would be:

```
public void DropV1.Ship()
public void DropV2.Ship()
```

Why it is like that?

Comment: The question would then be this, OK, let me use the class directly: `var ds = new DropShipping(); ds.Ship();` what should now happen? Which of the two methods should this call?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen None of the two. Visual Studio intellesense does not show neither of the two methods.

Comment: But of course if the language supported it, Visual Studio should too, I wasn't asking what the current IDE or compiler would do, I was asking what you think it should do.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Okay. I'm going back to the time when I haven't read the answer to my question. I don't really know what would happen because I will get confused about what it will call since they have the same method name in the class.

Comment: And that's why they couldn't do it like that. You can't have multiple methods with the same signature. The explicit implementation method is the best one as you're allowed to have one public method, and one explicit implementation per interface, as there is no confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a `private` it is called [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation). Within an `interface` all methods are `public` by definition so you don't need `public` keyword(even if you want you cannot use it here). The important to mention is that when explicitly implemented an `interface` methods are available only through an `interface` instance but not the `class` instance:

```
public class SampleClass : IControl
{
    void IControl.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
    }
}

IControl ctrl = new SampleClass();
ctrl.Paint(); //possible

SampleClass ctrl = new SampleClass();
ctrl.Paint(); //not possible

var ctrl = new SampleClass();
ctrl.Paint(); //not possible

((IControl) new SampleClass()).Paint(); //possible
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that by quoting the relevant parts from the docs.

Comment: Casting to the interface is possible too - `((IControl) new SampleClass()).Paint()`

Comment: @stuartd thanks, included as well.